# Как убрать линию под текстовой ссылкой ?

Tags: html

Как убрать линию под текстовой ссылкой?

```
<a href="soft1.html"><font color="#000000">софт</a>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="soft1.html" style="color: #000; text-decoration:none;">софт</a>
```

И почитайте про CSS поподробней.

Answer (score 2):

в css написать:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

ещё **font тег** закройте.

Comment: а можете это вместе написать

Comment: <a href="soft1.html" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">софт</a>

либо

<a href="soft1.html" style="text-decoration: none;"><font color="#000000">софт</font></a>

первый вариант лучше.